# Windows resources field overflows to next field

Tags: c, winapi, resources, borland-c++

I try to build resource file with Borland resources compiler, but the fields' data have to overflow. Even if I make padding with spaces for 30 characters, it overflows in some cases (in some cases not)... is there some binary format description of Microsoft resources files?

Here is the codes.

`resource.rc` file:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     1, 1, 1, 1
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",        "VAR_COMPANYNAME"
            VALUE "FileDescription",    "VAR_FILEDESCRIPTION"
            VALUE "FileVersion",        "VAR_FILEVERSION"
            VALUE "InternalName",       "VAR_INTERNALNAME"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     "VAR_LEGALCOPYRIGHT"
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1",   "VAR_LEGALTRAIDMARKS1"
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2",   "VAR_LEGALTRAIDMARKS2"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   "VAR_ORIGNALFILENAME"
            VALUE "ProductName",        "VAR_PRODUCTNAME"
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     "VAR_PRODUCTVERSION"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 1033, 1252
    END
END
```

`resource.bat` file:

```
@echo off

T:\bin\brcc32.exe -foTSEDO.res "C:\repos\gradlecpp\src\main\resources\resource.rc"
```

`resource.ps1` file:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

Remove-Item "TSEDO.rc"
Remove-Item "TSEDO.res"
Remove-Item "TSEDO.dll"

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$process = Start-Process `
    -NoNewWindow `
    -FilePath "$scriptPath\resources.bat" `
    -Wait `
    -PassThru
if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    "Error " + $process.ExitCode
    exit
}

$process = Start-Process `
    -NoNewWindow `
    -FilePath "T:\Bin\bpr2mak.exe" `
    -ArgumentList 'TSEDO.bpr -t..\template.bmk' `
    -Wait `
    -PassThru

if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    "Error " + $process.ExitCode
    exit
}

$process = Start-Process `
    -NoNewWindow `
    -FilePath "T:\bin\make.exe" `
    -ArgumentList '-fTSEDO.mak' `
    -Wait `
    -PassThru

if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    "Error " + $process.ExitCode
    exit
}

(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.CompanyName
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.FileDescription
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.FileVersion
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.InternalName
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.LegalCopyright
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.LegalTrademarks1
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.LegalTrademarks2
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.OriginalFilename
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.ProductName
(Get-Item TSEDO.dll).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

Here is Borland utils version:

```
c:\repos\torgovayasystema\EDO>brcc32 -h
Borland Resource Compiler  Version 5.40
Copyright (c) 1990, 1999 Inprise Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Here is output of build script:

```
PS C:\repos\torgovayasystema\edo> resources.ps1
Borland Resource Compiler  Version 5.40
Copyright (c) 1990, 1999 Inprise Corporation.  All rights reserved.
BPR2MAK C++Builder Project file to Makefile converter. Version 5.0
Copyright (C) 2000, Borland/Inprise Corporation

Loading project file
Loading template
Generating Makefile
.......................................MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 2000 Borland
        T:\bin\..\BIN\ilink32 @MAKE0000.@@@
Turbo Incremental Link 5.00 Copyright (c) 1997, 2000 Borland
Warning: Public symbol '_PATH_TO_SAVE_DIADOC_FILES' defined in both module C:\REPOS\TORGOVAYASYSTEMA\EDO\FMEDODOCOUT.OBJ
 and C:\REPOS\TORGOVAYASYSTEMA\EDO\FMEDODOCOUTSTATUS.OBJ
VAR_COMPANYNAME
VAR_FILEDESCRIPTION
VAR_FILEVERSION
VAR_INTERNALNAMEH↕☺LegalCopyright
VAR_LEGALCOPYRIGHTP¶☺LegalTrademarks1
VAR_ORIGNALFILENAME
VAR_PRODUCTNAME
VAR_PRODUCTVERSIOND
```

And the graphical one:

[image]

I have `Windows 7 SP1`.

Comment: Don't you need to add trailing null terminators manually in the resource script?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What is the specific goal? What is the expected behavior? What is the observed behavior?

Comment: IInspectable, please accept my condolences.

Comment: A `VS_VERSION_INFO` contains data only. You cannot encode any sort of formatting info into that, which appears to be what you're after. It would help a lot in answering the question if we could understand the problem. Updating the question with answers from my previous comment would be a step towards that.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in MSDN's [VERSIONINFO resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) example, you need to add a null terminator to the end of each string value in each localized `BLOCK`, eg:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     1, 1, 1, 1
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",        "VAR_COMPANYNAME\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription",    "VAR_FILEDESCRIPTION\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion",        "VAR_FILEVERSION\0"
            VALUE "InternalName",       "VAR_INTERNALNAME\0"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     "VAR_LEGALCOPYRIGHT\0"
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1",   "VAR_LEGALTRAIDMARKS1\0"
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2",   "VAR_LEGALTRAIDMARKS2\0"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   "VAR_ORIGNALFILENAME\0"
            VALUE "ProductName",        "VAR_PRODUCTNAME\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     "VAR_PRODUCTVERSION\0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 1033, 1252
    END
END
```

Comment: Thank you! I miss it... I thought that there are null terminators for padding....